# Could one synthesise unsubstituted "cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene"?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, stability

Is the cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene (non-aromatic benzene) possible to make or will it destabilize (or should I say stabilize?) into benzene?

Cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene is alternative name of benzene better describing its hypothetical, non-aromatic version. However they are similar and I was wondering if you made cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene would the electrons delocalise to form benzene or not?

Comment: but i thought benzene and cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene are the same!
how are they different?

Comment: @PrakharSankrityayan Edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot make (= synthesise) isolated, nonaromatic cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene<sup>[1]</sup> much like you cannot make (= synthesise) pseudoaromatic, biradicallic cyclobuta-1,3-diene. Hypothetical unsubstituted cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene will immediately give benzene, as [this answer demonstrates](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18925).

The only way to actually generate nonaromatic cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene is to apply an intramolecular constraint that disallows the aromatization. Since cyclobuta-1,3-diene is the most obvious antiaromatic, planar system, that will attempt to always adopt a localised double bond structure, structure **1** below immediately suggests itself as a model system for the localised cyclotriene.

[image: Synthesis of compound 1 by Diercks and Vollhardt]
**Scheme 1:** Diercks’ and Vollhardt’s synthesis of a cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene system **1**.

Indeed, that was the approach that Diercks and Vollhardt used to synthesise a model of cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene.<sup>[2]</sup> They report a crystal structure of **4** ($\ce{R}= \ce{TMS}$) wherein the alternating single and double bonds are clearly seen. The cyclobutyl sub-species adopts a cyclobutene-structure, meaning that the central cyclohexatriene ring’s double bonds are localised *between* the cyclobutane cores as indicated by the structure drawn. The outer benzyl rings are relatively aromatic (but not perfect hexagons).

---

**Note and reference:**

[1]: IUPAC nomenclature would allow systematically naming *benzene* as *cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene.* This is because IUPAC nomenclature assumes no knowledge of the chemistry of a given structure and requires names to be applicable *ab initio* and *a priori.* However, henceforth in this answer I shall make a distinction of (nonaromatic, localised, $D_\mathrm{3h}$-symmetric) cyclohexa-1,3,5-triene and (aromatic, $D_\mathrm{6h}$-symmetric) benzene.

[2]: R. Diercks, K. P. C. Vollhardt, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1986**, *108*, 3150. DOI: [10.1021/ja00271a080](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00271a080).