# How does the inverted Marcus region explain chemiluminescence?

Tags: physical-chemistry

The invert Marcus region offers one explanation of chemiluminescence, the process by which light is one of the products of a chemical reaction.

I tried reading one of Marcus's original papers on the subject [1], but I don't really get his argument. I get confused about which of the potential energy surfaces in his Figure (copied here, hopefully that's okay) that refer to the ground state reactant, ground state product, excited reactant, and excited product.

[image]

[1] R.J. Marcus (1965), "On the Theory of Chemiluminescent Electron-Transfer Reactions", *The Journal of Chemical Physics* 43(8):2654-2657

Answer (score 5):

Marcus theory of electron transfer shows that it is possible for a reaction with a large negative free energy ($-\Delta G$ ) to be slower than one with a less negative free energy. The region where this happens is called the 'inverted' region and is shown in figure (c) in your diagram. You can see that the energy of the products is far below that of the reactants but that there is still a substantial activation energy, that is the energy from the minimum of the R curve to the crossing point of the R-P curve on the left.

In fig (A) this is called the 'normal' region and the free energy is close to zero and there is still an activation barrier, in (b) the reaction is slightly exothermic has an activation energy and is still in the 'normal' region. What is missing is the case when the reaction is activationless, this lies between figs (b) and (c) and occurs when the P curve crosses the R curve at its minimum. In this situation the reaction has its maximum rate constant.

The figure shows some data illustrating the rate constnats for electron transfer in the normal(left side) activationless (top) and inverted inverted (right) regions vs $-\Delta G$. The data is for electron transfer from bases in DNA to different intercalated dyes. The fitted Marcus curve is the solid line one from classical Marcus theory the other from a quantum calculation.

Hopefully this will description allow you to follow the paper you have been reading. (You may also want to  look at BBA v811, p265, 1985)

It was not until late 1980's that Marcus theory was confirmed experimentally, first in the solid state and then with chemically linked donor and acceptor molecules as this prevents diffusion, which had hitherto greatly confused interpreting data, and also meant that the inverted region could not be observed.

[image: marcus curve]

The energetics for an electron transfer reaction

$$\ce{D^* +A \rightarrow D^+ + A^-  }$$ is

$$\Delta G = E^o_{D^+/D} -E^o_{A/A^-}-E_{s_1} +\epsilon_r$$

for an excited state $\ce{D^*}$ with energy $E_{s_1}$ and electrode potentials $E^o$. Marcus in the paper also includes a solvation term in a solvent, of dielectric constant $\epsilon$ to account for change in redox. This term can often be neglected but is

$$\epsilon_r = \frac{\Delta e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_o}\left (\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{2a}\right)\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{\epsilon_ar}\right)$$

where $\epsilon_a$ is the dielectric constant of acetonitrile, $2a$ is radius of donor + acceptor and *r* their separation.

The rate constant is calculated from
$$ k_\mathrm{et} = k^0\exp\left(- \frac{(\Delta G +\lambda)^2}{4\lambda k_\mathrm{B}T}\right)$$

where $\lambda$ is the reorganisation energy and is the vertical (positive) energy between the minimum of the acceptor potential and the donor potential. Its is determine experimentally from the maximum in the rate vs $-\Delta G$ plot as is $k^0$. In the plot $\lambda \approx 1~\mathrm{eV}$ and $k^0 \approx 10^{13} \pu{s^{-1}}$.

The chemiluminescent reaction can be considered as the reverse of the example given.

Comment: Well explained the basics of Marcus theory, but I'm still confused about how it relates to chemiluminescence. As far as I know, the barrier for chemiluminescence is lower than the barrier for crossing to the ground state via a non-radiative transition, but I don't see it in the figures.

Comment: I'm not sure that the Marcus paper does actually explain this; his papers are often very hard to follow. It mainly explains the eqns I give but in an old notation. In a chemiluminescence reaction the product is formed in the excited state so this would be R in the Marcus figure, so the process is backwards as it were. however,  now R is an excited state that emits to its ground state. This is below R and has v. approx the same shape but is not shown in the figure. I'm not sure even if Marcus theory does explain chemiluminescence. You will have to look for more recent papers.

Answer (score 1):

Researchers were of the opinion that, chemiluminescence could be a prime suspect to justify why it was so hard to observe Marcus inverted region in electron transfer reactions. To explain why so, let us assume that the equilibrium reactant and product curves have a large free energy gap relative to the reorganization energy, which would mean that the ET reaction occurs in the inverted region. In other words, the two curves would intersect on the conventional left side of the reactant parabola.

Now, because of the large free energy gap between the equilibrium ground states of the reactant (R) and product (P), there is a possibility that a lower-lying excited state of the product (P*) can be energetically favorably placed to cross the R potential at its minimum. If such a situation is prevalent, then a barrierless electron transfer reaction between R and P* would prefer to populate the excited state of the product, P.

As a result, an electron transfer reaction would end up populating the product excited state P* more than the ground state. That excited population can radiatively relax to the product ground state and result in a luminescent signal, which in this particular situation is known as chemiluminescence.

Comment: The reason the inverted region was not observed was that reactants were free to diffuse. As they come closer the electron transfer rate constant increases hugely and so all that is measured is a diffusion controlled rate constant. Keeping reactants in fixed positions allowed the inverted region to be observed as shown in the figure in my answer below.