Activation energy
Can a reaction have zero activation energy?
This was an assertion reason question in an entrance examination and different teachers had different answers. Please say weather this statement is true or not.

yes it can , and has been observed in electron transfer reactions where it produces the fastest possible rate constant.  (The activation energy cannot be negative.)

Even effectively negative Ea is possible in complex reactions.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18924/are-there-any-reactions-with-no-activation-energies https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95343/is-negative-activation-energy-possible

see also this answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/how-does-the-inverted-marcus-region-explain-chemiluminescence/63546#63546. the activationless reaction occurs at the maximum rate constant.
