# Is it possible to have a negative overall activation energy for a whole reaction mechanism?

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy, combustion, fuel

I am trying to find out correlation for ignition delay for alkane fuels. The activation energy part of the correlation gives me a negative value. 
For the ignition delay formulation, is it possible to have an overall activation energy part being negative?

$$\tau = P^aT^b\phi^c\exp\left(\frac{E_\mathrm{a}}{RT}\right)$$

Comment: Well, it sure is possible and does happen sometimes for complex reactions, dunno if it applies for your case, though.

Comment: This might be helpful:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95343/is-negative-activation-energy-possible