# Will increasing the temperature of solid reactants increase rate of reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, energy

When temperature of aqueous and gaseous reactants increase, the rate of reaction increases since the particles will move more quickly so frequency of effective collision increases. But does this work for solid reactants as well? I know that the particles will vibrate more vigorously, but is it sufficient to result in higher rate of reaction?

Comment: yes, in fact a lot of solid state reactions require heating to "push" it along at an appreciable time scale.

Comment: For your liquid/gas statement, it depends what counts as a reaction https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95343/is-negative-activation-energy-possible (Not my DV though.)